# Issue when using the shared object created with Python C Extension

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I am writing a Python C Extension on Linux (Rhel 6.3) with Python 2.6.6.
There is a shared library lib_common.so and i have written a C code(Python c Extension) to call the methods in the library lib_common.so. 
I have created a setup.py which includes the library and the C code.
It was able to create the module mymod.so (mymod) successfully.
I copied this so to the /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ directory and i also copied lib_common.so to the same directory
Now when i invoke Python interpreter and import the module (mymod) i am getting an error which says that the function which is present in lib_common.so is undefined

> ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mymod.so: undefined symbol: My_Fun

My doubt is whether i am missing any step here because of which i am getting this error?

Comment: Did you try to put the `lib_common.so` into the usual position for shared libraries(e.g. under `/usr/lib64`)?

Comment: Yes as i mentioned i have copied the lib_common.so to the directory where the mymod.so is copied and also i have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Although `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should work, the pythonic way is to define `library_dirs` and `runtime_library_dirs` (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#library-options)). Apart from that, have you tried to write a minimal C program (no extension) that calls the library, compile, link and run it?

Comment: Yes..i wrote a small C program without any so dependency and was able to call that from Python successfully. But with dependent lib_common.so i am facing the issue